# Why is there no flat mechanical keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I am surprised that I cannot find any flat mechanical keyboard. Is there any technical reason for that, or the market is just too small?

The mechanical keyboard I use has an actuation point at 2mm (but the travel distance of the keys is set to 4mm…), so I don't see any technical hurdle to manufacture a flat mechanical keyboard but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "flat keyboard"?

Comment: Ultra thin keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do exist. They are just hard to find.

I love mechanical keyboards, but they are too high, which forces you to place your hands/wrists at a very unhealthy angle.

Here is a flat mechanical keyboard (the "Rapoo KX"): http://www.pcworld.com/article/2860856/rapoo-kx-review-the-mechanical-keyboard-enthusiasts-tiny-traveling-companion.html

Company's website: http://www.rapoo.com/ProductShow.aspx?PType=CHTi%2f0TqNIc%3d&PID=uCupl3PJuVw%3d

There is also a discussion about them here:

http://deskthority.net/workshop-f7/flat-key-caps-progress-thread-t8415.html

https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=60531.0

http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1292723-flat-key-mechanical-keyboard

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea why someone downvoted your answer. One downside of the  Rapoo KX is that they use their own mechanical keys, which have a higher actuation force than some Cherry MX such as Cherry MX red. Are you aware of any other flat mechanical keyboards with lower actuation force?

Answer (score 1):

If you ever take apart a laptop, you will notice that although thicker than non-mechanical keyboards, they can still make mechanical keyboards to be quite thin. The following keyboard (the one in my primary laptop) uses [scissor-switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Scissor-switch_keyboard), which although I don't have the exact dimensions for, would estimate results in a keyboard thickness of about 8 mm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci0kNZvoqKQ

There is one problem, though: the aluminum plate on which everything is fastened does give a bit when bent. "Flexible" and "mechanical keys" don't go well together; a mechanical keyboard inside of a backpack getting slightly bent is more likely going to get permanently damaged than a membrane keyboard. (In fact, since membrane keyboards are happily bent, you can even create [keyboards that roll up](http://www.geekalerts.com/u/scosche-freekey-rollup-keyboard.jpg), something that would be impossible with mechanical keyboards)

If you want to use a scissor-switch keyboard as an external keyboard, the primary hurdle would be securing this aluminum plate in such a manner that it doesn't bend, which would require a plastic enclosure, adding to the thickness of the keyboard.

And in the end, most mechanical keyboards (or at least [the ones I would take apart as a child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Dome-switch_keyboard)) use the exact same principle as a membrane keyboard, but instead having each switch covered by a "plastic mechanical shield" that gives different feedback when depressed. So if you want to make a keyboard as thin as possible (and cheaper!), just remove the mechanical plastic bit entirely.

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm not an engineer; I'm just a computer repair guy familiar with broken keyboards.

Comment: I would imagine flat mechanical keyboards exist, this is simply what I believe is the primary motivation to why they aren't commonly manufactured.